# How to get file location of an song in iPod library in iOS

Tags: ios, mpmediaitem, mpmediapickercontroller, swift2

I have the reference of a `MPMediaItem` when user selects an audio from the iPod library. I am getting the `asset url` of that item by using

```
     let url = item.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL)
```

But this is not giving me the exact physical location of the file, instead it is giving me an url w.r.t iPod library.

```
ipod-library://item/item.mp3?id=1840064795502796074
```

Is there a way to get the `physical url` of a song from iPod library?

EDIT - actually I want to extract `NSData` from the physical file and send it to my `backend server`, so i need the physical file URL and not the relative URL

Comment: so do you want to send music file of music library to your server ?

Comment: Exactly......Thank you for your comment

Comment: HI Lion is it possible? If it's possible give me a solution.

Comment: I don't think that it is possible because apple have strong restrictions about music! but, I am not sure!

Comment: Can you give your Skype id?We are doing this kind of app.But they were accessing itunes library: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/handy-audio-editor-trim-audio/id998073416?mt=8

Comment: have you downloaded this app ? and have try it that how this app is working ?

Comment: Yep!.I downloaded the app.It's working good.If i click the song and done button...The song will be displayed and played.We can trim and merge the song also in our app.

Comment: refer my answer and links mentioned in it!

Comment: Sure.I will check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to copyright protection you can only play songs from music library. You can't access row audio file! But there are some tricks that can help like you can `export music` because you can do mixing type of stuff and after creating your new edited file you have new copy of your music file and you can send it I thing, but can't send directly from library like you send photo and video! You have to export it with `export session` first!

Refer [this so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364997/pick-music-from-ios-library-and-send-save) for that!

You should refer [Apple sample code for that](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AddMusic/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008845-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

And [this so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077725/application-crashed-while-importing-songs-from-ipod-library-in-iphone-for-ios-5) and [this tutoria](http://iphoneghostrider.blogspot.in/2014/05/import-music-and-save-it-to-document.html) also may helpful to you!

Comment: But it's very useful.